# Gem Does Nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, osx-snow-leopard

I guess I messed things up a little bit:

I wanted to play around with Ruby on Rails a little bit. I installed it a year ago but never used it. Till now.

Because of some problem a ran into I wanted to start from beginning with a fresh install. I uninstalled the Rails gems (3.0.7 and 3.1.1) and followed this guide for a fresh install: http://eddorre.com/posts/rails-ultimate-install-guide-on-os-x-snow-leopard-using-rvm-homebrew-and-passenger

But now gem does nothing - when I type `gem install bundle` in my terminal the cursor goes straight to the next line. Even `gem list` or `gem --help` doesn't work. I get no error messages.

I have no clue what happened. Some thoughts?

Comment: What's the output of `which gem`?

Comment: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/gem

Comment: I'd blow away your `.rvm` and start over *completely*, including your `rvm`.

Comment: ok....so I just remove the .rvm directory or is there any uninstall routine?

Comment: Just delete the whole thing; since you're starting from scratch you can just reinstall everything, "clean slate".  There will be some recompiling, but it's likely you'll want to install new versions of things anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do a full reinstall of rvm:

`rvm implode`

and start again:

`bash <<(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)`

If you try to recover the existing environment, there are some options to rvm that can be useful:

> **debug**      - show info plus additional information for common issues
>
> **upgrade**    - Lets you upgrade from one version of a ruby to another,
>   including
>                  migrating your gemsets semi-automatically.
>
> **cleanup**    - Lets you remove stale source folders / archives and
>   other miscellaneous
>                  data associated with rvm.   repair     - Lets you repair parts of your environment e.g. wrappers, env files and
>                  and similar files (e.g. general maintenance).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to start over anyway, I would highly recommend that you use [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). Do the "single user install" and these gem problems should disappear entirely. Then if you get a specific error message, post that so we have something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Please run this command in your console:

```
gem env
```

This command will return your gem environment, and one more correction: I guess it should be '`gem install bundler`' not '`gem install bundle`'.

Comment: 'gem env' results in nothing.

Comment: Could u post your PATH variable, in linux you could get it as echo $PATH, but I'm not sure how in OSX

Comment: `Users/username/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin` `echo $PATH` worked